# Probability involving law of total probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My question reads:

A box has $100$ normal dice, plus $40$ dice whose face numbers are $2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6,$ and plus $40$ dice whose face numbers are $1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5$. One die was chosen at random.

a) What is the probability of this die rolling a $6$?

b) If I just rolled one $6$ with this die, what is the probability that I get a $6$ on my next roll of it?

**My solution for a)**

Let $R$="rolling a 6", $A$= 'normal dice", $B$="even dice", $C$="odd dice"

I found the $P(A)=100/180$, $P(B)= P(C) = 40/180$ and then I found $P(E|A)=1/6$, $P(E|B)=2/6$ and $P(E|C)=0$.

Then I used the law total probability and my answer was $1/6$ which seems a bit odd to me so I just wanted to know if maybe my probabilities are off. Does my answer seem correct?

Mostly, I am having trouble approaching part b. I see this would be another situation of conditional but I think this would not be as simple as applying the formula for conditional. How would I incorporate the different dice? Would this be double conditioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) your result is correct
$$P(R)=P(R|A)P(A)+P(R|B)P(B)+P(R|C)P(C)=
\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{100}{180}
+\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{40}{180}
+0\cdot \frac{40}{180}=\frac{1}{6}.$$

For b), if you just rolled one 6 ($R$) with this die then it is normal ($A$) or even $(B)$ and the probability of another $6$ ($R$) is
$$p:=P(R|A)P(A|R)+P(R|B)P(B|R).$$
Note that $P(A|R)=P(R|A)P(A)/P(R)=5/9$ and $P(B|R)=P(R|B)P(B)/P(R)=4/9$. Hence
$$p=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{9}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{9}=\frac{13}{54}.$$

Comment: @Sam Any more doubts?

Comment: I am not too sure where the 5/9 and 4/9 come from. I was thinking of making my events G=the die lands on a 6 the first roll and F=the die lands on 6 the first and second throw and then using double conditioning because now we have two events.

Comment: @Sam They follow from a property of the conditional probability. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Assuming_conditional_probability_is_of_similar_size_to_its_inverse

Comment: Noted. I understand now and actually was able to find the answer myself. There was actually a part c asking the probability of rolling another 6 on the next roll if I just rolled two 6's. Would this be similar?

Comment: @Sam Yes, it is similar.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I used the law total probability and my answer was 1/6 which seems a bit odd to me so I just wanted to know if maybe my probabilities are off.

No, your calculation is fine.   They just choose the proportions of fair, evens-biased, and odds-biased die carefully.

$$\tfrac 59\tfrac 16+\tfrac 29\tfrac 26 +\tfrac 29\tfrac 06 ~=~ \tfrac 9{9\cdot 6} ~=~\tfrac 16$$

---

For (b) Consider that there are $180$ sixes which you could have rolled with equal probability, and $100$ of which are the only ones on their die and the other $80$ are all on evens-biased die.   So the probability that you have a fair die is $5/9$ and the probability that you have an even die is $4/9$.   (Can you see from where else those numbers can be reached?)

Now use the Law of Total Probability.

Comment: I see what you mean by focusing on only those two dice, but I am not too sure how you got those numbers. Wait did you do 100/180 for the fair and 80/180 for the even die because now we are focusing on the 6? Would it make a difference if I now made my 2 event to be rolling a 6 on the first roll for one event and the other event being rolling a 6 on the first and second roll?